# Codeigniter in virtual host error 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, virtualhost, codeigniter-3

### codeigniter 3.0.2

#### About my localhost env config

> PHP 5.2+ apache 2.4+

print my localhost CI Log:

```
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:35 --> Helper loaded: file_helper
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:36 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:40 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:40 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:40 --> File loaded:       E:\phpStudy\WWW\newab\application\views\admin/login.php
INFO - 2015-11-09 21:06:40 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2015-11-09 21:06:40 --> Total execution time: 6.1245
```

#### It worked and everything is ok!

---

#### About Virtual Host env config

> PHP 5.2+ Apache 2.2+

print Virtual Host CI Log:

```
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> Language Class Initialized
ERROR - 2015-11-09 20:22:56 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

#### It report 404 page not found and everything is 404!

why? compare them, i find at **Loader Class Initialized** occur this error.

I aslo try $config['uri_protocol'], use

- PATH_INFO
- REQUEST_URI
- QUERY_STRING

it worked in my localhost but all 404 in Virtual Host, so it can't get it.

Please help me.

Comment: mind posting your `htaccess` ?

Comment: did you change the base url on the config file? can you post some code to see how you are loading the index?

Comment: @TerisL I don't use .htaccess.

Comment: @jpganz18 $config['base_url'] = '' nothing I set it. The key is on my localhost it worked, post to virtual host it don't working then 404

Comment: why dont you configure the base_url with the new url?

Comment: @jpganz18 The base_url maybe not the cause of this error,I get it by renamed file name start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CodeIgniter 3.0.x it is essential that all controller file names start with an upper case character. Make sure your files are named this way.

For instance, in `/application/controllers/` the file `a_controller.php` must be named `A_controller.php`

Equally important is the rule for an initial capital letter for the class name in the controller file. For instance this is wrong

```
class a_controller extends CI_Controller {
```

This is correct.

```
class A_controller extends CI_Controller {
```

Comment: You're right! I get it by renamed file name.Thanks a lot.